# How to refer library in subfolder in php

Tags: php

I have the line 
    $pdf = new FPDF();
which works if the FPDF library is in the root directory, but how do I use it if the library is in a sub folder. I have tried

```
$pdf = new mySubfolder/FPDF();
```

but it doesnt work. Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,
only include with directory structure.

```
require_once("mySubfolder/fpdf.php");
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) *(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0, PHP 7)*

```
<?php
   namespace myMainFolder;

   use mySubFolder\PDF;

   $pdf = new PDF();

   var_dump($pdf);
?>
```